# How to mimic MVC's checkbox -> bool model binding?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox, model-binding

I've got an editor template which renders out a checkbox:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Follow)
```

Which renders something like this:

```
<input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Follow field is required." id="Follow" name="Follow" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="Follow" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

AFAIK the hidden field is something to do with catering when an unchecked box isn't sent to the server or something.

Anyway, if i take a look at the `Request.Form["Follow"]` when the checkbox is *checked*, i see a value of "true,false".

How do i coerce a `bool` from this value? Do i simply ignore the second field? (e.g the hidden field).

I'm doing this is a base controller (protected method, invoked from child controller), so i don't have a strongly-typed view model, only the raw `Request` object.

Can anyone help? Or alternatively, if someone could point me to where in the MVC source code this happens, i could take a look myself, but not sure where to start looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know, the extra hidden field is because if the checkbox is NOT checked, that input will not be submitted with the form and therefore we need the hidden field with the value of `false`.

So the only solution is can think of is this:

```
var rawFollow = Request.Form["Follow"];
var rawFollows = rawFollow.Split(',');
if (rawFollows.Count() > 1)
{
   rawFollow = rawFollows[0];
}
```

But this seems hacky (and what about the *order* of the elements on the page, what if for some reason the hidden field was FIRST, then it would always evaluate to false), which is why i'm wondering how the MVC source does this.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct the hidden field is just so the form will be submitted to the server. Because if the form had just checkboxes that are not checked then nothing will be submitted and the server would not know to set them to false.

1. You only require 1 hidden field per form, you do not need one per checkbox. But if your making your own control it is hard to tell if a hidden textbox is already on the field or not. If you know you are always going to have a textbox or select list etc somewhere else on your forms you do not need a hidden textbox at all
2. You can rename your hidden textbox to anything name it  "dummy" or something different to the checkbox name so  Request.Form["Follow"]; will only return the value of the check box not need to split. You never need to check the value of the "hidden textbox".

On a side note you shouldn't be using  Request.Form["Follow"]  you Action method should have a parameter like this instead  "bool? follow"

Comment: i dont get what your saying. first of all, i'm not responsible for rendering the checkbox/hidden field, MVC does that when i call `Html.CheckBoxFor`. If i rename the field to "dummy", and i uncheck the field, then there wont be a value in `Request.Form["Follow"]`, so tht wont work. That's why the hidden field is there. As for the side note, i can't use the parameter, because as i said in my question, this isn't an action method, this is a method in a base controller, executed manually by actions. I don't want to litter all my action methods with that additional parameter.

Comment: Sorry I misread your post - I thought you were trying to write your own control to mimic and replace the built in checkbox. I now see you just want to use the one MVC provides but access it.  Your solution looks ok - I would use the string contains method to look for true or false instead of split. That way the order of fields would not matter

Answer (score 2):

MVC helper renders checkbox input control with two input fields, the checkbox and the hidden, because the browser do not send a value for checkbox input field if the checkbox is not selected. If you do not use auto mapping, you need to parse the input value that you receve from your form.

Use this simple rule to detect the checkbox:

```
var rawFollow = Request.Form["Follow"];
if (rawFollow.Contains("true"))
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: i dont think this has anything to do with automapper. it's the built in MVC default model binding that does the job.